# Using Liquid inside data file

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Is it possible to use liquid markup inside a data file in jekyll?

I'd like to do something like this:

HTML:

```
        {% for entry in site.data.nav-social %}
            {% if entry != null %}
                <a href="{{ site.url }}{{ entry.href }}">
                    <i class="{{ entry.icon }}"></i>
                </a>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

data file called nav-social.yml:

```
- icon: fa fa-twitter fa-3x
  href: {{ site.twitter }}
```

and in the config.yml:

```
twitter: ...
```

But the resulting url is:

```
   <a href="http://localhost:4000{}">
      <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-3x"></i>
   </a>
```

**Question: How can I use the infos from the config file inside a data file?**

Answer (score 1):

Liquid tag from data file to page/post, I've tried to do it today : Not Working.
This implies that the page/post is parsed two times.

But you can put your datas in config, under a certain key, eg: social.

```
social:
  twitter: 
    name: twname
    icon: icon
  facebook
    name: fbname
    icon: .....
```

And get them with **site.social.key** and even loop the **site.social** hash.